# Debug configuration file (.xcconfig)

Tags: xcode, configuration, xcconfig, xcode-project

Is there a way of checking whether your xcode project is using the .xcconfig configuration file  with which you have supplied it?

What I mean is, if there is some way of 'printing' a statement eg debugging, like #warning, #error, printf, etc...?

The reason being is that I have set up some configurations, and I feel they are not being used...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open the project navigator and select "Build Settings". If you have specified the config files correctly and added any setting to that file, a new column will appear, one for the xcconfig file for each target and on for the project as whole. The column to the far left is a "sum" of all you settings, and there you can verify that the settings you look for are set.

**EDIT:** *Adding some pictures to show the columns with different config file settings.*

Build settings without any property in the projects xcconfig file:
[image: Without any setting in the project config file]

And the same with some settings in the projects xcconfig file:
[image: With setting in the project config file]

The same applies for the Target as seen in the following two pictures:

No settings in the targets config file:
[image: Without any settings in the targets config file]

Some settings in the targets config file:
[image: With settings in the targets config file]

Check out this beginners tutorial for more visual examples and a step-by-step guide:
http://www.jontolof.com/cocoa/using-xcconfig-files-for-you-xcode-project/

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, i think that is actually a valid solution to just confirming that your project acknowledges the xcconfig files you have provided it with. Thanks for the visual examples too.